# Describe how solutions behave as t increases and how their behavior depends on the initial value $y_0$ when $t=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y'=-y(3-ty)$

**My attempt**

$y'=-3y+ty^2 \Rightarrow y'+3y=ty^2 \Rightarrow \frac{y'}{y^2}+\frac{3}{y}=t$

Let $v(t)=\frac{1}{y(t)}$, so that $v'(t)=\frac{-\frac{dy(t)}{dt}}{y(t)^2}$ and hence $-v'(t)+3v(t)=t \Rightarrow v'(t)-3v(t)=-t$.

Let $\mu(t)=e^{-3 \int dt}=e^{-3t}$

$\frac{d}{dt}[v(t)e^{-3t}]=e^{-3t}[v'(t)-3v(t)] \Rightarrow \frac{d}{dt}[v(t)e^{-3t}]=-te^{-3t}$

$\int\frac{d}{dt}[v(t)e^{-3t}]=-\int te^{-3t}dt$

Using integration by parts I see that $-\int te^{-3t}dt=\frac{t}{3}e^{-3t}+\frac{1}{9}e^{-3t}+C$

Thus, $v(t)e^{-3t}=\frac{t}{3}e^{-3t}+\frac{1}{9}e^{-3t}+C \Rightarrow v(t)=\frac{t}{3}+\frac{1}{9}+Ce^{3t} \Rightarrow y(t)=\frac{9}{3t+1+Ce^{3t}}$

I know that $\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} \frac{9}{3t+1+Ce^{3t}} \to 0$

But how do we reason that if $y_0 \le 9$, $\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} y(t) \to 0$; and that if $y_o>9, \lim\limits_{t \to \infty} y(t) \to \infty$?

Comment: @user577215664 $y(t)=\frac{9}{3t+1+\frac{9-y_0}{y_0}e^{3t}}$ So if $y_0 >9$, the denominator would be $\infty -\infty$ as $t \to infty$?

Comment: If $-1<C<0$ then the denominator has a root, the solution a pole at finite time. The solution ends at this finite time, the behavior at larger times does not exist, is undefined.

Comment: @LutzLehmann is there a particular reason for viewing $C \in (-1,0)$? What do you mean when you say the solution is a pole at finite time?

Comment: Its just about the mean value theorem. If $C<0$, the denominator falls to $-\infty$. Its value at $t=0$ is $C+1$. So in the stated interval the denominator has a root for $t>0$, the expression for $y$ thus a pole at the same place.